# Measure memory usage of a certain datastructure

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, measurement

I'm trying to measure the memory usage of my own datastructure in my Tomcat Java EE application at various levels of usage.

To measure the memory usage **I have tried** two strategies:

1. Runtime freeMemory and totalMemory:

   ```
   System.gc(); //about 20 times
   long start = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

   useMyDataStructure();

   long end = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

   System.out.println(start - end);
   ```
2. MemoryPoolMXBean.getPeakUsage():

   ```
   long before = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
   List<MemoryPoolMXBean> memorymxbeans = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();
   for(MemoryPoolMXBean memorybean: memorymxbeans){
       memorybean.resetPeakUsage();
   }

   useMyDataStructure();

   for(MemoryPoolMXBean memorybean: memorymxbeans){
       MemoryUsage peak = memorybean.getPeakUsage();
       System.out.println(memorybean.getName() + ": " + (peak.getUsed() - before));
   }
   ```

Method 1 does not **output** reliable data at all. The data is useless.

Method 2 outputs negative values. Besides it's `getName()` tells me it's outputting `Code Cache`, `PS Eden Space`, `PS Survivor Space` and `PS Old Gen` seperately.

**How can I acquire somewhat consistent memory usage numbers before and after my `useMyDataStructure()` call in Java? I do not wish to use VirtualVM, I prefer to catch the number in a `long` object and write it to file myself.**

Thanks in advance.

---

edit 1:

`useMyDatastructure` in the above examples was an attempt to simplify the code. What's really there:

```
        int key = generateKey();
        MyOwnObject obj = makeAnObject();
        MyContainerClass.getSingleton().addToHashMap(key, obj);
```

So in essence I'm really trying to measure how much memory the `HashMap<Integer, MyOwnObject>` in `MyContainerClass` takes. I will use this memory measurement to perform an experiment where I fill up both the HashMap and MyOwnObject instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all sizing objects in java is non-trivial (as explained very well [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2003-12/02-qa-1226-sizeof.html)).

if you wish to know the size of a particular object, there are at least 2 open source libraries that will do the math for you - [java.sizeof](http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/) and [javabi-sizeof](https://code.google.com/p/javabi-sizeof/)

now, as for your specific test - System.gc() is mostly ignored by modern (hotspot) jvms, no matter how many times you call it. also, is it possible your `useMyDataStructure()` method does not retain a reference to the object(s) it creates? in that case measuring free memory after calling it is no good as any allocated Objects might have been cleared out.

Comment: Thanks radai. I hope my edit 1 is an answer to your question.

Comment: @Caroline - i think it did. if all you need is to size your specific Map object any of the libraries will do fine. just make sure to read the fine print about static, final fields and possible overcounting :-)

Comment: Sounds good. I'm working on getting this running in my Netbeans Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

You could try https://github.com/jbellis/jamm, this works great for me.